# C: analyze bottleneck of C programs

Tags: c, debugging

My C program is efficiency critical. Some functions are called millions of times, so I would like to know how much time is spent on each function, giving me sth like this:

```
Total time: 100s
forward(): 20s;
align(): 15s;
...
others: 1s.
```

Is there any debugger can perform such analysis? I am using Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu, and using gdb to debug. Some guy suggested [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), but I did not find any suitable. I found there are some questions talking about c# or php or perl profiling, any suggestions for C? Thanks.

===========================================

Follow up: thanks very much for all help,  gprof seems really nice. Here is a manual link: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html.

A question about interpreting the summary:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name    
 61.29      9.18     9.18                             bwa_print_sam_SQ
 21.96     12.47     3.29                             bwt_sa
  4.01     13.07     0.60                             bns_coor_pac2real
  3.87     13.65     0.58                             bwt_match_exact_alt
  2.60     14.04     0.39                             bwa_read_seq
  1.00     14.19     0.15                             bwt_match_gap
  0.80     14.45     0.12                             seq_reverse
```

If I am not wrong, it says the function bwa_print_sam_SQ takes 61.29% of the total time. But my program runs for 96.24 seconds, this function should run around 60 seconds. Why the column "cumulative" seconds is only 9.18? The manual says:

```
cumulative seconds
    This is the cumulative total number of seconds the computer spent executing this functions, plus the time spent in all the functions above this one in this table.
```

And I use the parameter

```
"gprof -f pe_sai2sam_se_core -f bwa_print_sam_SQ -f seq_reverse ./peta > gprof",
```

where function "pe_sai2sam_se_core" calls "bwa_print_sam_SQ" in a big while loop. Why the report says:

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     61.3    9.18    0.00                 bwa_print_sam_SQ [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[8]      0.8    0.12    0.00                 seq_reverse [8]
-----------------------------------------------
```

It did not say anything about pe_sai2sam_se_core... Why?

Comment: valgrind with [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) is pretty good.

Comment: Enterprise editions of Visual Studio include a profiler.  Glowcode and a few other exist, just search locally here for profilers and enjoy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a debugger. What you need is called a profiler. Since you mention Ubuntu, you probably want to start with `gprof`.

Here's how you can use `gprof`:

- Disable all compiler optimizations for your program (`-O0`) - optional of course
- Add the `-g` and the `-pg` flags
- Rebuild and run the program as usual
- At this point your program should have produced a `gmon.out` file in the cwd
- Use `gprof` to inspect data:

  ```
  gprof ./your_program > prof
  ```

Now you can view the `prof` file. It begins with the flat profile which simply tells you how much time it's spending in various functions.

Comment: @Cai Shaojiang: gprof can be often missleading, search here on SO for other profiler tools.

Comment: Just curious, why the `-O0` ? Seems odd to profile the unoptimized code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman To prevent the compiler from messing around. Some time ago I was wondering how come a function that did *nothing* was using 70% of the time. All it did was call some functions that didn't even appear in the profile. It should have been apparent but it wasn't for me. The compiler was inlining stuff. So, in light of that story I am always afraid the compiler will do something nasty behind my back that will confuse the profiler. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: But now you might see 'bottlenecks' that the compiler could easily solve.

Comment: To pitch in on this answer: I always use gprof. Valgrind also has a plugin (or module, I'm not sure how they call their add-ons - aah! another word!) called Callgrind, and people often recommend it. But I find it hard to use and don't really understand the need for such complex profiler output (maybe it has better uses in multi-thread runtimes or dynamic code). The one disadvantage of gprof is that it lives inside your binary, its code isn't the same. Valgrind is a VM that runs your (intact) code.